# How to write a Representable instance using only Distributive properties?

Tags: haskell, typeclass, representable, distributive

Say I've got a `Distributive` instance written for some complex custom type, `Foo`.
Is it possible to write `Foo`'s `Representable` instance using only the properties available from its `Distributive` instance? And, if not, then why is `Distributive` a superclass of `Representable`?

Comment: You appear to have the meaning of a superclass constraint backwards. e.g. there are `Applicative`s which are not `Monad`s, and we have `class Applicative f => Monad f`. (And see also [`distributeRep`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/adjunctions-4.4/docs/Data-Functor-Rep.html#v:distributeRep) which witnesses the inclusion of `Representable` in `Distributive`.)

Comment: I know it has been a while, but anyway: I have rewritten my answer into something that hopefully will be more informative.

Answer (score 3):

The superclass relationship between `Distributive` and [`Representable`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/adjunctions-4.4/docs/Data-Functor-Rep.html)...

```
class Distributive f => Representable f where
```

... means that if `f` is a `Representable`, then it also must be a `Distributive`, and not the other way around. When used for subclassing, `=>` should be read as "is a prerequisite of", rather than "implies". (This is, in fact, opposite to how it is when `=>` is used for constraints in type signatures. Purescript [uses `<=` for subclassing](https://github.com/purescript/documentation/blob/master/language/Differences-from-Haskell.md#type-classes) for this very reason.)

For most other pairs of superclass and subclass, the story would end here. `Distributive` and `Representable`, however, have a special relationship, in that `Distributive` functors are actually representable, as stated by the documentation of both [`Distributive`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/distributive-0.6/docs/Data-Distributive.html)...

> Categorically every `Distributive` functor is actually a right adjoint, and so it must be `Representable` endofunctor and preserve all limits. This is a fancy way of saying it isomorphic to `(->) x` for some `x`.

... and `Representable`:

> A `Functor` `f` is `Representable` if `tabulate` and `index` witness an isomorphism to `(->) x`.
>
> Every `Distributive` `Functor` is actually `Representable`.
>
> Every `Representable` `Functor` from Hask to Hask is a right adjoint.

The hierarchy is set up the way it is, with `Distributive` as the superclass, because `Distributive` is meant to have a simpler interface [which is expressible in Haskell 98](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/user/edwardk/moore/for-less#distributive-functors--represent-), unlike `Representable` (which uses a type family) and [`Adjunction`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/adjunctions-4.4/docs/Data-Functor-Adjunction.html) (which is a multi-parameter type class). From a more conceptual point of view, while the distributive laws imply that every `Distributive` is representable, they are not enough for figuring out what the representation is. Getting our hands on the representation requires specifying it, either directly (as in `Representable`) or indirectly (as in `Adjunction`).

Comment: I never thought about the fact that the arrow is the wrong way around in a class declaration! Sounds like the Haskell committee made a mistake back in the day.

Comment: @dfeuer I feel both choices are defensible. Personally, I find `Applicative f <= Monad f` a little awkward because `<=` also suggests ordering, which might justify choosing to write it as `Monad f <= Applicative f` instead. It is interesting to note that [Wadler's original propsal for type classes](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/papers/class-letter/class-letter.txt) didn't actually use any sort of arrow to introduce subclassing in a class declaration.

Comment: Another option would have been to swap the positions: `class Integral a => (Real a, Enum a) where ...`. That's not too far from Wadler.